# Custom View Navigation in Extended Fiori Application

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm working on MyTime off extension App. I have a requirement of navigation to Custom View (FullScreenPage to FullScreenPage) from S2Custom View.

I'm able to navigate to my Custom View but I'm getting split app instead of detail page.

https://answers.sap.com/questions/188414/custom-view-navigation-in-extended-fiori-applicati.html

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you use „View Replacement“ ?
Views of a delivered standard application can be replaced to adapt the application to the customer needs.
If the extension points provided for view extension are not sufficient to meet the requirements of the custom application,
you can replace the standard view with a custom view.
Please see also [View Replacement](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/98861cf90b874e3394b666cfb347ff0b.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response. My requirement doesn't meet the customer needs. So, I have gone through the custom view.